# Importing answers from a Google Form into another Google Sheet, then adding a column for notes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have been using a Google Spreadsheet with a master list created from a Google Form. I created a new tab to rearrange the order of the entries to the newest ones on top.

However after those cells have been copied over and new entries are created from the form, if I put notes next to those cells, the cells (that were copied over) move down with each new entry though my notes column stays. It doesn't move down as well with the row I put it on. How do I fix this?

I haven't been able to find any examples. The imported data is the only thing moving down with new entries, while my working cells next to them don't move. Please advise.

Here is the formula I was using:

```
=query(Master!A2:I, "select * order by A desc", 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Notes are bound to the address of the cell and not to the content of the cell.

A note is metadata to the cell. So, I am afraid you cannot just fix it.

When a **new response** arrives, a new line is not added. It is just **new content added** after the latest content, leaving the exising content untouched.

**When you execute the query you *"rearrange"* the position of the content of the cells**. Not the cells. The same happens when executing any formula for that matter.

### A comparison

**When you think of notes, think of formatting**.
Formatting is bound to the cell. Not the content. That is why, when for example cell `B3` is filled with green, text bolded and assigned a date format, it will still retain these characteristics no matter the content.

### The *"exception"*

Not really one. Just the confirmation to the rule. Think of the following 2 scenarios:

1. Select a cell (**single click**). <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy. Next, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste. **Both formatting and content get transferred**.
2. Select the content of a cell (**double click**). <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy. Next, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste. **Just the content tranferred**, free from formatting.

**Notes behave the same way**. When you for example, place a note in cell `B2` it stays in `B2` while data is added, altered or shifted around in the sheet through formulas. If you want to move it, you have to manually `Copy+Paste` it to different cell.